# Swing and JavaFX concurrency

Tags: swing, javafx-8

Is there a way to avoid concurrency when using Swing embedded in JavaFX8 (swingNode) or vice versa (JFXPanel)  ?
I have two threads (the EDT and the FX application) which manage the UI, this can cause unexpected results...

Comment: you have to make sure that all views are accessed _exclusively_ on their respective thread - switching with PlatForm.runLater/SwingUtilites.invokeLater

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not officially possible currently. In both frameworks changes to the structure can only be done on the respective UI thread.

However, in the future this may change, but I do not know of any concrete plans that oracle may have and I cannot find an appropriate task in their jira.

edit: I found the specific thread about this on the javafx mailinglist:
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-August/009541.html

jira issue: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30694

appearently there is an experimental system property that can be set to enable a "single threaded mode": -Djavafx.embed.singleThread=true